# How to select the C/C++ compiler used for a GitHub Actions Job?

Tags: c++, continuous-integration, github-actions

Is there a way to select the default C/C++ compiler (such as gcc or clang) for a GitHub Actions job?

To be precise, I want CMake to pick up different compilers without hacking the CMake command.

Ideally, by extending the build matrix. Similar to the Node.js version, as described in the official docs:
https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-workflow#configuring-a-build-matrix

Something like that:

```
[..]
strategy:
  matrix:
    compiler: [gcc, clang]
[..]
```

Comment: Why in the world does this have two close votes? The question directly involves programming tools.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#how-do-i-use-a-different-compiler recommends using the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables to choose a compiler, and I like your idea of using a matrix to run under different compilers. So now we just need to look at https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrix and see how to use the matrix. Here's the example snippet they show:

```
runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
strategy:
  matrix:
    os: [ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04]
    node: [6, 8, 10]
steps:
  - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
    with:
      node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}
```

As you can see, specifying a `foo` variable under `matrix:` then creates a `matrix.foo` value that you can reference elsewhere. So you'd do something like this:

```
name: Build master

on: [push]

strategy:
  matrix:
    compiler: [gcc, clang]
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Run CMake
      env:
        CC: ${{ matrix.compiler }}
      run: cmake --your-args-here
```

Comment: I overlooked that they picked up `node` as `node-version` for the `setup-node` action. Your solution is the way to go. It is easily extendable to also set CXX. Although, I think the matrix must be part of the actual job: `jobs.<job_id>.strategy.matrix`.

Comment: I slightly prefer calling CMake with `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER={foo}` and define `foo` in 
`env`. At least on Travis CI, messing with CXX directly doesn't work with manually installed compiler versions (say GCC-svn or Clang-svn nightly builds).

Comment: This answer got me 90% of the way there, but I had to put the strategy keyword inside `build` (see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/managing-complex-workflows#using-a-build-matrix)) to get everything to work.